# Парсинг и отправка комментариев Youtube

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вообщем, нужно реализовать парсинг рандомного комментария из чата в прямой трансляции Youtube, а в дальнейшем отправлять его под своим именем.

Я пробовал через selenium WebDriver, но не получается залогинить аккаунт гугла.

Ещё я пробовал через Youtube API, но там ничего не понятно.

Может будут идеи, как это можно реализовать по другому.

Comment: На ютубе и так много порноботов, зачем еще?)))

Comment: Да, понимаю)) Я просто хочу понять как они работают и реализовать для себя на питоне

Comment: @AntonNikolaev Если есть идеи, то можешь дать наводку)